# Arguments passed to the eq() function in the context of jQlite and Angularjs tests

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

I have the following code:

```
element = $compile('<pagination ...')($rootScope);
lis = function(){
 return element.find('li');
}

var nextPageItem = lis().eq(-1);
var page2 = lis().eq(2).find('a').eq(0);
```

I am not sure what the arguments **-1** and **0** mean in the above context.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

.eq( index ):

> An integer indicating the 0-based position of the element.

.eq( -index )

> An integer indicating the position of the element, counting backwards
>   from the last element in the set.

So for example, your HTML markup look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

When you use:

```
$( "li" ).eq( 2 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

The result of this call is a red background for your list item 3. Note that `eq()` is zero-based index.

In the other hand, when you use:

```
$( "li" ).eq( -2 ).css( "background-color", "blue" );
```

This will make your list item 4 turn to blue, since it is two from the end of the set.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zFZka/)**

Comment: A demo using Angular's jQlite instead of jQuery - [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwGgzN?editors=101). Make sure you use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of just `document.querySelector`!